# Upgrading from Grails 2.x to 3.x

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle, ggts

I am working on a Grails 2.3 project, and they ask me have to do a study to see if it is possible to pass on the 3.x version of grails.
you can tell me what is it advantageous to switch to the version 3.x, and what's the best way for the update properly.
at the environment working I guess GGTS not supporting GRAILS 3.x, then it is mandatory to work with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: This is a discussion more than a specific question.  I suggest that you start the discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grails-dev-discuss.

Answer (score 0):

This section of official documentation covers the topic nicely

> Upgrading from previous versions of Grails - Reference Documentation
>
> http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.htmlv

---

You can also check the following presentation on the topic of the migration

> Migrating from Grails 2 to Grails 3
>
> http://www.slideshare.net/SpringCentral/migrating-from-grails-2-to-grails-3

---

Yes, GGTS currently does not support Grails 3.x, so IDEA Ultimate edition is probably the best choice as described in [STARTING WITH GRAILS3 – CHOOSING AN IDE](http://whiteprompt.com/grails/starting-with-grails3-choosing-an-ide/).